# How do I fetch all reactions from a specific message? [Discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

So, I want to make a command for my bot which can fetch all reactions from a given message ID and store these three categories into arrays, for each reaction:

- the name of the reaction (eg. :smile:)
- the users who reacted (eg. RandomUser#4654, ILikePotatoes#1639)
- and how many people reacted with this emoji (eg. Count: 2)

I've tried using the ReactionCollector, but it doesn't work for reactions added prior to the event being called. I've also tried using an external module called *discord-fetch-all* but all it does is either sending `Promise { <Pending> }` or `undefined` when I use `.then()`.

*PS: I've already set up a command handler that takes a message ID for argument.*

Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the specific message you want to be check for reactions by using:

```js
const messageReacted = client.channels.cache.get('channelId').messages.fetch('messageId')
```

Then, you can go through each reaction in the message's cached reactions by using `forEach`

Then, in the `.forEach`, you can get the emoji name by using `reaction._emoji.name`, the number of users who used this reaction by `reaction.count` and all the users who reacted on the message by fetching them: `await reaction.users.fetch()`.

Your final code might look something like:

```js
const messageReacted = await client.channels.cache
    .get('channelId')
    .messages.fetch("messageId");

messageReacted.reactions.cache.forEach(async(reaction) => {
    const emojiName = reaction._emoji.name
    const emojiCount = reaction.count
    const reactionUsers = await reaction.users.fetch();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, when I run your code inside of a messageCreate event and two if loops (I don't know if that matters), I get "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules". Did I make a mistake anywhere?

Comment: That's easy. All you have to do is add async to the top of the client.on like: `client.on('messageCreate', async message => {})`

Comment: Thank you, your advice worked :). Will mark this as solved!

Comment: I tried it myself and it worked. However I noticed that the collection only includes the first 100 users of a reaction. Is there any way to get the full list?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do it, since it's been some time since I've used it. Let me look around in the docs and come back to you